# Gradle dependency runtimeOnly but not in test

Tags: java, gradle, testing, dependencies

Is there a way to specify `runtimeOnly` dependency which is not available during the test runtime?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? To me this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: A possible scenario: I would like to use `slf4j-simple` at runtime in my command line application, but a custom implementation of an SFL4J service provider (or logger binder in SLF4J 1.7.x) at test runtime. Since SLF4J does not like more than one service provider (or logger binder) to be present in the classpath, `slf4j-simple` must be excluded from the test runtime classpath.

I achieved this with an explicit exclude in my `build.gradle.kts` file:

`configurations.testRuntimeClasspath { exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-simple") }`